# How to assign two different types to the same tagged value?

Tags: enterprise-architect

How can i assign two different types to the same tagged value in MDG. 
For Example:- There's a tagged value with the name TAG1 whose type is 
Type=String; and also Type=RefGUID;. Now how to make this tag properties attain both the types i.e., It should be of string as well as RefGUID.

Comment: do you have an example of such a tagvalue in existing technology, I know you are already talking of such a tagged value, but do you know in which mdg it exists specifically?

Comment: Tricky. I'll have a look. But on a first shot: you should name them differently since the have different content. If you buy fruits and you name them all apple you hardly can get any bananas.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely this is not possible. The XMI profile for a tagged value looks like this (taken from the White Board Circle):

```
        <TaggedValues>
          <Tag name="fill" type="boolean" description="" unit="" values="true,false" default="false"/>
          <Tag name="nameVisible" type="boolean" description="" unit="" values="true,false" default="false"/>
        </TaggedValues>
```

If you add a duplicate tagged value for `fill`, only the first will be visible. So instead of a boolean you now see an int, but not both.

```
        <TaggedValues>
          <Tag name="fill" type="int" description="" unit="" values="1,2" default="1"/>
          <Tag name="fill" type="boolean" description="" unit="" values="true,false" default="false"/>
          <Tag name="nameVisible" type="boolean" description="" unit="" values="true,false" default="false"/>
        </TaggedValues>
```

Conclusion: do as I commented. Name them differently.

Comment: or make a structured tagged value if its relevant

Comment: @MartinGrégoire You should post that as answer. I guess that's a valid alternative.